# Foreach loop with dynamic index

Tags: c#, foreach

In my if-statement i increase the value for counter. I use var counter as the index for subcategories. After the if statement it jumps out from my loop. I would like it to begin looping subcategories[1] or [2] etc. How can i continue looping index 1, 2, 3 for my subcategories list?

```
int counter = 0;
int eachCounter = 0;
foreach (var item in filteredList[0].subcategories[counter].questionanswer)
{
    int questionsCounter = filteredList[0].subcategories[counter].questionanswer.Count;
    eachCounter++;
    if (eachCounter.Equals(questionsCounter))
    {
        counter++;
        eachCounter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply use for? Why is it a foreach you don't even use item?

Comment: Why are u using a foreach loop instead of a for loop? For comes with a usable index by default.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `for`, since this isn't going to work. The `foreach` will iterate over the initial `questionanswer` on the first iteration, it won't go further on the next one.

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < filteredList[0].subcategories.Count; counter++)
{
    var item = filteredList[0].subcategories[counter].questionanswer;
}
```

If you want to iterate over both lists (the inner and the outer list), use two `foreach` statements or `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop

```
int eachCounter = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < filteredList[0].subcategories[i].questionanswer.Count; i++)
{
    int questionsCounter = filteredList[0].subcategories[i].questionanswer.Count;
    eachCounter++; // I am not sure why you are doing this or what the purpose is
    if (eachCounter.Equals(questionsCounter))
    {
        eachCounter = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use for each to loop through `filteredList[0].subcategories` array this way:

```
int counter = 0;
int eachCounter = 0;
foreach (var item in filteredList[0].subcategories)
{
    // item is filteredList[0].subcategories[0], filteredList[0].subcategories[1] and so on.
    int questionsCounter = item.questionanswer.Count;
    eachCounter++;
    if (eachCounter.Equals(questionsCounter))
    {
        counter++;
        eachCounter = 0;
    }
}
```

I don't know the logic behind your program here, I see you're using `counter` as a loop variable and changing it in between, so it might not iterate through all elements of `filteredList[0].subcategories[]` serially. However, if you want to traverse through all elements of `filteredList[0].subcategories[]` serially using `foreach`, this is how its done.

Edit:

For traversing through subcategories[0], [1] and so on:

```
foreach (var item in filteredList[0].subcategories)
{
    // item is filteredList[0].subcategories[0], filteredList[0].subcategories[1] and so on.
    foreach(element in item)
    {
        //element is item[0], item[1] and so on i.e
        // filteredList[0].subcategories[0].questionAnswer[0]
        // filteredList[0].subcategories[0].questionAnswer[1]
        // filteredList[0].subcategories[0].questionAnswer[2]
        // .
        // .
        // filteredList[0].subcategories[1].questionAnswer[0]
        // filteredList[0].subcategories[1].questionAnswer[1]
        // .
        // .
    }
}
```

Comment: Inside subcategories[0] i need to loop through that list also, thats why i use counter

Comment: Then use 2 loops, one for iterating through subcategories and one for iterating through subcategories[0]. Using counter and trying to traverse through the list of lists with a single loop is plain complication in code without any gain in performance. I've updated my answer to traverse through subcategories[0], [1].